# How to execute MakeFiles on Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm almost new to this platform. I couldn't find any related question to what I'm asking over here. In case its there, please provide me the link to the answer. 
So, what I'm trying to do is on this website I could find many code submissions (https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/Round-1-Submissions)
I wanted to learn a little more about them, by executing them on my machine. But I don't have Ubuntu, is there any way to execute them on Visual Studio 2015? (For example lets consider the first submission BIG QUAKE, after downloading and extracting, what should be my steps to execute it on Visual Studio?) If someone knows, please help me. 
Thanks for your patience

Comment: Link flags in that Makefile include libcrypto and libssl, so you'd need a windows port of openssl (libeay32.dll and .lib and libssl32.dll and .lib plus header files) first to be able to try to compile this with Visual Studio.  After that, load all the .c into a VC project, set project properties on the linker option to point to the libeay32 and libssl32 .lib files, make sure the .dlls are in your path, and then build.

Comment: @JohnH I agree...

Comment: I see. Thank you all